# Can I use Kolmogorov-Smirnov test with estimated distribution parameters if I'm not interested in p-value?

Tags: distributions, statistical-significance, normal-distribution, estimation, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

I want to compare a list of 12 candidate distributions to sets of observed data, to see which estimated candidate distribution fits each data set best. Given a list of candidate distributions, I fit each distribution to the observed data, then perform a k-s test to assess the fit. I want to rank these estimated distributions by the test statistic `D` to order them by how "far off" they are from the observed data.

I understand that the k-s test should not be used to test goodness of fit of a distribution with parameters estimated from the sample. Other questions/answers on this site discuss this issue. However, my impression is that this is because it no longer follows the null distribution which affects the critical p-value.

But if I'm ignoring p-values and only interested in sorting the estimated distributions by the test statistic, is my method valid?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "valid". What are you trying to achieve by doing this?

Consider, for example, that distributions with more parameters would be expected to fit better. 

Let's take a simple situation where one distribution includes another as a special case that's not a boundary point (e.g. exponential vs gamma, exponential vs Weibull). The more general one will *always* fit better -- so you could never choose the exponential *even if you generate your data from an exponential*.

Comment: @Glen_b given that concern, is there a best practice to do this? I want to explore proportionally how often each candidate distribution is the best fit across this set of datasets. So, for example, I might find Weibull provides the best fit 50% of the time, lognormal 20% of the time, power law 5% of the time, etc...

Comment: If they're all two-parameter distributions and the estimators all have standard errors of $O(n^{-\frac12})$, arguably you can compare fits this way. I don't know of a good way of making Komogorov-Smirnov distance comparable if that's not the case. It sounds like a research problem. Is there a particular reason you want that approach to measuring fit? If we were comparing exponential to Weibull, we could perhaps use something along the lines of AIC (essentially, a penalized likelihood approach to fit rather than K-S distance)